# Sum of all even Fibonacci numbers code never stops - Java

Tags: java, while-loop, fibonacci

This is from project Euler, problem 2. I wrote the following seemingly innocent code:

```
public class FibonacciEven {
    public static void main(String[] stuff) {
        long sum = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while(fib(i) <= 40) {
            boolean even = fib(i) % 2 == 0;
            if(even) {
                sum += fib(i);
            }
            else {
                continue;
            }
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
    public static long fib(int n) {
        long prev1 = 0;
        long prev2 = 1;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            long savePrev1 = prev1;
            prev1 = prev2;
            prev2 = savePrev1 + prev2;
        }
        return prev1;
    }
}
```

I did read about how the Java method for working out Fibonacci numbers is quite memory hungry, but, as you can see, I scaled my limit down to *40*, and it still doesn't get to the end, so I assume that I have gotten some syntax horribly wrong. What bit of the code is making it run forever? And if all of this really is due to the fact that the method takes so much time to run, can anyone suggest a better way?

EDIT: ok, now my code looks like this:

```
public class FibonacciEven {
    public static void main(String[] stuff) {
        long sum = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while(fib(i) <= 40) {
            boolean even = fib(i) % 2 == 0;
            if(even) {
                sum += fib(i);
            }
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
    public static long fib(int n) {
        long prev1 = 0;
        long prev2 = 1;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            long savePrev1 = prev1;
            prev1 = prev2;
            prev2 = savePrev1 + prev2;
        }
        return prev1;
    }
}
```

This time it ignores the 2 (index 3) in the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: I read that it can take several hours to complete.

Comment: @Jon SKeet has the right answer as to why it loops forever. But here's another suggestion unrelated to your question. You're doubling the amount of work you're doing by calling fib(i) twice in the loop. You should be assigning the return value of fib(i) to a variable in the loop and then checking its value. So it should probably be rewritten as a do/while loop to do that.

Comment: Hours? Memory? Hmm. Not convinced. In any case--how have you tried debugging so far? Have you worked through some examples using pencil and paper?

Comment: Have you considered building an array of the fib values < n so you can refer back to them instead of constantly recalculating?

Comment: @hsanders - thanks, I put it into a variable :D

Comment: @Bluefire tbroberg's technique is called memoization, it's an optimization technique. It will help a lot because it makes it so you do much fewer iterations to calculate the next number.

Comment: Yes, tbroberg's suggestion will help. The reason being that rather than starting back from 0 and 1 for your prev1 and prev2, you can just access the array at n-2 and n-1 (depending on where your memorization ends I suppose). Essentially, rather than re-processing it, you're throwing more RAM at it so that it won't need to re-process it.

Comment: For timing reference, recently wrote some fibonacci generators. Using the memoization technique, was able to generate all numbers whose results would fit in a signed 64-bit int (F(n), n=92) in about 0.1 milliseconds using python. Using the classic recursive approach, I gave up after about 40 minutes in C++ and had only computed about the first 50 numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `even` is false, you end up continuin without updating `i` - so it'll loop round again and do exactly the same work again, so `even` will be false again, etc...

I suspect you just want to take out the `else` block.

Comment: Ah, thanks! So if I put the `i++` *before* my if, will it work?

Comment: @Bluefire NO. Don't put it before the if.

Comment: So it does, and really quickly too. Thanks!

Comment: @Bluefire Wait, so it apparently worked? Uhh where exactly did you put it. Something doesn't sound quite right lol. Is the number you get correct?

Comment: @Sephallia - I posted my last comment before I saw yours; why shouldn't I put it in front of the if?

Comment: @Bluefire You do your Fib math inside of the if. If you put the incrementation before the "if" you are calculating not for "i" but for "i+1" and you do this multiple times.

Comment: @Bluefire: If you increment `i` *before* the `if` block, then when you add `fib(i)` to `sum`, you're adding the wrong value.

Comment: This time, it works fine, apart from the fact that it ignores the 2 at the beginning. How come?

Comment: @Bluefire this is really hard to tell without being able to see your code, could you edit and put the updated version?

Comment: @Bluefire: It doesn't ignore the 2. Put this line after the line that increases `sum`: `System.out.println(fib(i) + " " + sum);` and you'll see it works fine.

Comment: Oh, sorry for that slip up D:

Answer (score 2):

You're also redoing a lot of work every time.  I'd recommend memoizing the previously calculated values as you have them.  That and recursion are your friends here.

[image]

I'd say this would be far more efficient than looping every time.

Answer (score 0):

You can always try to compute numbers in much more efficient way. Here is a quite good description how to do this in `O(nlogn)`: http://blog.codility.com/2012/03/omicron-2012-codility-programming.html

(Problem in this link is much more complicated but the method of computing Fibbonacci numbers is the same)

Answer (score -3):

I think the problem is initially for i=0 case it boolean returns false and it is executing the
else part , try incrementing the i value in both if or else.

```
if(even) {
            sum += fib(i);
i++;
        }
        else {
      continue;
  i++;
      }
```